# Function that handles a file reading

Tags: python, function, file

I have a file that I have to read. In every line, there is a name, age, height, and weight. There are a lot of lines in the file and I only need the names.  Here is my code:

```
import random
import string

dictionary = {}
lst = []

with open("persons.dat","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        items = line.split(',') #this makes this ['Bill Johnson', '31', '196', '93']
        key = items[0]
        dictionary[key] = []
        for i in range(1,len(items)):
            dictionary[key].append(int(items[i]))
    #print(dictionary)

    for key in dictionary.keys():
        lst.append(key)
    print(lst)


def generateGroup(sizeOfGroup):
    for names in range(sizeOfGroup):
       random_names = random.choice(lst)
    print(random_names)
```

My code gets all of the names in the list as intended. The code works fine up to `generateGroup()`

I need a function that would ask for the size of a group (some number) of the list and give random names from that list.

I don't know how to implement that function.  I kind of get the logic of the function, but I don't know where I should put the function in the code (like which line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.sample` does exactly this.

```
def generateGroup(sizeOfGroup):
    print(random.sample(lst, k=sizeOfGroup))
```

`random.sample` returns a list. You could accumulate the list yourself

```
random_names = []
for names in range(sizeOfGroup):
     random_names.append(random.choice(lst))
print(random_names)
```

but `random.sample` ensures that you won't select the same name twice.

Once `generateGroup` is defined correctly, you still need to call it with an argument:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an integer, try again")

generateGroup(n)
```

Comment: This doesnt really answer my question

Comment: You mean, where do you get the value to pass *to* `generateGroup` (which, incidentally, doesn't work as intended, because it will only print a single random name)?

Comment: What I meant is, for eg: right now it prints back only the list of names but the def generateGroup(sizeOfGroup) function doesnt work at all, like it doesnt print anything. 
It should take the lst I created from reading that file and the function should ask for some number, lets say 4 and print out 4 random names from that lst.

Comment: Are you *calling* `generateGroup` at all? What you show only *defines* it.